# apply_filters to featured image

Tags: theme-development, functions, filters, post-thumbnails, embed

I have a page where I have embedded the page using these lines of codes at function.php:

```
//------Embed Content------
//Title
function CustomFunction_ShowPage_Title($id) {
    $post = get_page($id);
    $title = apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title);
    echo $title;
}

//Content
function CustomFunction_ShowPage_Content($id) {
    $post = get_page($id);
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
    echo $content;
}
```

How do I do this for featured images too?
do I simply replace `the_content with` with `the_post_thumbnail`?
if so, what do I put on the second parameter?
do I simply go `$post->post_thumbnail`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`get_the_post_thumbnail( $id )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail):

```
$thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, 'post-thumbnail' );
```

Comment: Thank you sir for taking the time to answer.
Does this apply to both pages and post? :)

Comment: Yes, this works with any post type: post, page or custom.